# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api-v3.igdb.com/games...' ... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api-v3.igdb.com/games/?search=nfs&fields=name,genres.name,first_release_date,cover.*&limit=10&offset=0' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

i am not understarding how to solve this error.

i need help for cross origin in localhost:3000

show code like this:

```
var headers = {'user-key': '**********************',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
}

    var dataurl = 'https://api-v3.igdb.com/games/?search=nfs&fields=name,genres.name,first_release_date,cover.*&limit=10&offset=0'

axios.post( dataurl, '' , { crossDomain: true,headers:headers })
.then(resData => {
    console.log(resData)
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.error(err)          
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

CORS policy is handled by the server not the clinet -- you can't make a cross origin request to a server if the server doesn't return the Access-Control-* headers in response to a preflight request.

Not all requests are subject to CORS checking -- it is the presence of the "user-key" header that is triggering it from your page.  But what you are doing is exactly what CORS is designed to prevent from happening: your site is causing the user's browser to send user's information to a third-party site.

Comment: explain more i am not under standing perfectly.

Comment: You are trying to do something that is not allowed. Your web page is trying to send an HTTP request to a different site. If that were possible, I could, for instance, put javascript code on my blog that, when you viewed it, would post to facebook to add me as your friend.
CORS is a technique that a site can use to allow other sites to send it requests. So igdb.com could use CORS to let you do what you are trying to do. You can't use it to force them